# Loop through data frames based upon name

Tags: r, loops

I have another simple r question that hopefully someone can help with. I have a series of dataframes that have a repetitive name structure. I would like to loop through them and perform some analysis. Here is hardcoded example of what I want to do using some fake data:

```
#Create some fake data
n1 = c(2, 3, 5, 7) 
s1 = c(1, 1, 2, 0) 
b1 = c(6, 0, 0, 0) 
Tank001.df = data.frame(n1, s1, b1)

n2 = c(1, 2, 4, 6) 
s2 = c(2, 2, 0, 0) 
b2 = c(8, 9, 10, 0) 
Tank002.df = data.frame(n2, s2, b2)

n3 = c(7, 12, 0, 0) 
s3 = c(5, 3, 0, 0) 
b3 = c(8, 9, 10, 4) 
Tank003.df = data.frame(n3, s3, b3)
```

The first action I would like to automate is the conversion of 0 values to "NA". Here is the harcoded version but I would ideally automate this dependant on how many Tankxxx.df dataframes I have:

```
#Convert zeros to NA
Tank001.df[Tank001.df==0] <- NA
Tank002.df[Tank002.df==0] <- NA
Tank003.df[Tank003.df==0] <- NA
```

Finally I would like to complete a series of queries of the data, a simple example of which might be the number of values smaller than 5 in each dataframe:

```
#Return the number of values smaller than 5
Tank001.less.than.5 <- numeric(length(Tank001.df))
for (i in 1:(length(Tank001.df))) {Tank001.less.than.5[i] <- sum(Tank001.df[[i]] < 5,na.rm=TRUE)} 
Tank002.less.than.5 <- numeric(length(Tank002.df))
for (i in 1:(length(Tank002.df))) {Tank002.less.than.5[i] <- sum(Tank002.df[[i]] < 5,na.rm=TRUE)} 
Tank003.less.than.5 <- numeric(length(Tank003.df))
for (i in 1:(length(Tank003.df))) {Tank003.less.than.5[i] <- sum(Tank003.df[[i]] < 5,na.rm=TRUE)}
```

Ideally I would also like to know how to write the results of such simple calculations to a new dataframe. In this case for example Less.than.5$TankXXX etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 for reproducible example with source data and desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a `list` of your `data.frame`s and use a combination of `lapply` and `sapply` as follows:

```
TankList <- list(Tank001.df, Tank002.df, Tank003.df)
lapply(TankList, function(x) {
  x[x == 0] <- NA
  sapply(x, function(y) sum(y < 5, na.rm = TRUE))
})
# [[1]]
# n1 s1 b1 
#  2  3  0 
# 
# [[2]]
# n2 s2 b2 
#  3  2  0 
# 
# [[3]]
# n3 s3 b3 
#  0  1  1
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift solution. Not having used lists before, what is the syntax for obtaining the mean of n1, s1 and b1 for my simple example? E.g. the desired result of the above example would be 1.67, 1.67, 0.67

Comment: @user1912925, Sorry, but I don't understand how you arrived at those results. Can you explain and I'll see what I can do to help out?

Comment: @AnandaMahto  I think he wants the mean of all `n*` ,etc. (but his values are incorrect)  Either an `sapply` across the k-th elements of each list, or turn the results into a matrix and calculate `colMeans` ?

Answer (score 3):

This also works with a single `lapply` and `colSums`:

```
l <- list(Tank001.df, Tank002.df, Tank003.df) # create a list

lapply(l, function(x) colSums("is.na<-"(x, !x) < 5, na.rm = TRUE))

# [[1]]
# n1 s1 b1 
#  2  3  0 
# 
# [[2]]
# n2 s2 b2 
#  3  2  0 
# 
# [[3]]
# n3 s3 b3 
#  0  1  1
```

Comment: +1, but certainly not the most memorable or commonly seen syntax!

Comment: +1! might I suggest something like `l <- mget(ls(pattern='Tank.*df$')` to avoid creating list by hand...

Comment: @agstudy Good idea! The `mget` functions requires an environment argument: `mget(ls(pattern='Tank.*df$'), globalenv())`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Yes but no need in this case. It the same argument(environment) as `ls`.